# can't load files when trying to publish my threejs project on github pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, github-pages, react-three-fiber

I've been experimenting with react three fiber and wanted to publish a project on github pages. I did a build of my project and deployed it on pages. I get an error in the console that it can not load my files:

`main.bb26e057.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Here is a link to the repository: https://github.com/olvard/repossumtory/tree/main/possumtory ,

Here is a link to the pages site: https://olvard.github.io/repossumtory/possumtory/build/

I've tried fiddleing with different filepaths but i don't understand why `npm run build` would give me incorrect filepaths anyways.

Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try providing the `homepage` property in the `package.json` of the React App.

In your case, `https://olvard.github.io/repossumtory/possumtory/build/` is the start url.

So modify include this line in your package.json.

`"homepage": "https://olvard.github.io/repossumtory/possumtory/build/",`

**Edit:**

Adding to your comment: The model fails to load at the first attempt because of your `model.js` on the last line.

It should be `useGLTF.preload('opossum.glb')` instead of `useGLTF.preload('/opossum.glb')`

Comment: this seems to have fixed the initial failure to load the js files, but now i can't load the model.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a package called [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages). It's a scripted way of uploading your site using the pages functions of GitHub and also supports custom configuration options on commit.

All you need to do is run:

```
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
```

Then create a new file. Inside this file simply insert this code:

```js
var ghpages = require('gh-pages');

ghpages.publish('path-of-dir-to-commit', function(err) {
  if(err) {
   console.log(err);
} else {
 console.log("success");
});
```

You can read more on the npm site for the configuration options such as naming the repo it generates if non is found, etc.